# Rearranging tab views doesnt work

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar Controller with 8 tabs (views).

When I tap More... and then Edit the modal view that lets me rearrange the tabs appear, but rearranging does not work. Tabs do not stay to the place I am dragging them.

Do i need to enable something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drag them, are you trying to rearrange them in the cluster view that pops up? If you are that won't work, you drag the one that you want to move down to the TabBar, and it will replace the existing one.

[image]